# Pandas dataframe look for key in dict, write key in new column according to value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key-value

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   {'ID': 1,'A': [{'name': 'lifestyle'}, {'name': 'economy'}, 
                          {'name': 'politics'}, {'name': 'climate & environment'}]}, 
                   {'ID': 2,'A': [{'name': 'sport'}]}, 
                   {'ID': 3,'A': [{'name': 'climate & environment'}]},
                   {'ID': 4,'A': [{'name': 'sport'}]},
                   {'ID': 5,'A': [{'name': 'politics'}, {'name': 'world'}]},
                   {'ID': 6,'A': [{'name': 'economy'}, {'name': 'politics'}]}
                  ])
```

Every value in col A belongs to a category. Those categories are in a hardcoded dict (categories.txt):

```
dict= {'lifestyle':'cat1',
'economy':'cat1',
'politics':'cat2',
'climate & environment':'cat2',
'sport':'cat3',
'world':'cat4',
'news':'cat3'}
```

My goal is to look for every key and write this key(s) in a new col named after the value (cat1, cat2,...)

Here is what I got so far:

```
df['A'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['A']]
```

```
# read in the dict
d = {}
with open("categories.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(":")
        d[key] = value


di = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv.split(',')}


for k, v in d.items():
    if v == 'cat1':
        df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(k), 'cat1'] = k
    elif v == 'cat2':
        df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(k), 'cat2'] = k
    elif v == 'cat3':
        df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(k), 'cat3'] = k 
    else:
        df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(k), 'cat4'] = k
```

Right now, if there is more than one key per row this will be written as the next category which is not the right way. How do I get every key (one or multiple keys per cell) in the right column named after the values?
Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'cat1':['lifestyle, economy','nan','nan','nan','nan','economy, politics'],
                   'cat2':['politics, climate & environment','nan','climate & environment','nan','politics','nan'],
                   'cat3':['nan','sport','nan','sport','nan','nan'],
                   'cat4':['nan','nan','nan','nan','world','nan']})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `explode` and `apply` to extract values from your first dataframe then map with your dict before pivot:

**Update**

> Merging the ID col back with the categories does not work because the amount of entries is different. The ID col is crucial

```
out = df['A'].explode().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
out['category'] = out['name'].map(d)
out = out.pivot_table(index='index', columns='category',
                      values='name', aggfunc=', '.join) \
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
out = df[['ID']].join(out)
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
   ID                cat1                             cat2   cat3   cat4
0   1  lifestyle, economy  politics, climate & environment    NaN    NaN
1   2                 NaN                              NaN  sport    NaN
2   3                 NaN            climate & environment    NaN    NaN
3   4                 NaN                              NaN  sport    NaN
4   5                 NaN                         politics    NaN  world
5   6             economy                         politics    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: IIUC, it should help to get what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, but is there an alternative to explode? Merging the ID col back with the categories does not work because the amount of entries is different. The ID col is crucial.

Comment: I updated my answer. The ID column is back to the output. Can you check, please?